# SQLAlchemy: Finding all matching rows from a table with results from another query

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I have four tables:

- Page

  - wikiPageID
  - url
- Collection

  - collectionID
  - wikiPageID
- PageReference (joining table)

  - wikiPageID
  - referenceID
- Reference

  - referenceID

For any given URL corresponding to a row in the `page` table, I want to return all the references assigned to any sibling pages which might belong to the same collection.

I feel there may be a more efficient way of doing this. So far I've broken it into a set of queries and am only half way there.

```py
    # Get all ReferenceData from Reference table for ID
    wikiPageID = ""
    url = request.json['url']

    # Get WikiPageID from Page table where Page.url = request.json['url']
    for item in db.session.query(PageModel).filter(PageModel.url == url).values('wikiPageID'):
        wikiPageID = item[0]
        #print(wikiPageID)

    for item in 
    db.session.query(CollectionModel).filter(CollectionModel.wikiPageID == wikiPageID).values('collectionID'):
        collectionID = item[0]
        #print(collectionID)

    # Get all WikiPageID's from Collection table where WikiPageID EXISTS
    result1 = db.session.query(CollectionModel).filter(CollectionModel.collectionID == collectionID).values('wikiPageID')

    ## THIS IS WHERE IT STARTS GOING PEAR SHAPED
    # Get all ReferenceID from PageReference where WikiPageID EXISTS
    result = db.session.query(PageReferenceModel).filter(PageReferenceModel.wikiPageID.in_(result1) )

    schema = CollectionSchema()
    return schema.dump(result, many=True), 200
```

On my last query I'm attempting to nest the previous query results. As I'm attempting to filter the results by the IDs passed from the previous result. I feel I'm going about this all wrong and can't quite figure where to go from here.

## SQLAlchemy Models

```
class CollectionModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Collection"

    collectionID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    wikiPageID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Page.wikiPageID'), nullable=False)
    Page = db.relationship("PageModel")

class PageModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Page"

    wikiPageID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    langCode = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    summary = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    lastUpdated = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)

class PageReferenceModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "PageReference"

    pageReferenceID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    wikiPageID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Page.wikiPageID'), nullable=False)
    referenceID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Reference.referenceID'), nullable=False)
    Page = db.relationship("PageModel")
    Reference = db.relationship("ReferenceModel")


class ReferenceModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Reference"

    referenceID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    langCode = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    isGov = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    domain = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    suffix = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    publishDate = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    youtubeId = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    langCheck = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

I ended up doing a series of if statements on the results of the prior queries. Still most likely inefficient. But it works.

## Collection GET

```
    # Get all ReferenceData from Reference table for ID
    wikiPageID = ""
    url = request.json['url']


   # Get all ReferenceData from Reference table for ID
    wikiPageID = ""
    url = request.json['url']

    # Get WikiPageID from Page table where Page.url = request.json['url']
    for item in db.session.query(PageModel).filter(PageModel.url == url).values(PageModel.wikiPageID):
        wikiPageID = item[0]
        #print(wikiPageID)

    for item in db.session.query(CollectionModel).filter(CollectionModel.wikiPageID == wikiPageID).values(CollectionModel.collectionID):
        collectionID = item[0]
        #print(collectionID)

    # Get all WikiPageID's from Collection table where WikiPageID EXISTS
    wikiPageIDResult = db.session.query(CollectionModel).filter(CollectionModel.collectionID == collectionID).values(CollectionModel.wikiPageID)

    wikiPageArray = []
    for item in wikiPageIDResult:
        wikiPageArray.append(item[0])
        print("Wiki Page Array: ", wikiPageArray)

    #Get all ReferenceID from PageReference where WikiPageID EXISTS
    wikiPageReferenceResults = db.session.query(PageReferenceModel).filter(PageReferenceModel.wikiPageID.in_(wikiPageArray)).values(PageReferenceModel.referenceID)

    wikiPageReferenceArray = []
    for item in wikiPageReferenceResults:
        wikiPageReferenceArray.append(item[0])
        print("Wiki Page Reference Array: ", wikiPageReferenceArray)

    referenceResult = db.session.query(ReferenceModel).filter(ReferenceModel.referenceID.in_(wikiPageReferenceArray))

    schema = ReferenceSchema()
    return schema.dump(referenceResult, many=True), 200
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use join:

```py
    result = db.session.query(PageReferenceModel)\
             .join(CollectionModel, CollectionModel.wikiPageId == PageReferenceModel.wikiPageId)\
             .join(PageModel, PageModel.wikiPageId == PageReferenceModel.wikiPageId)\
             .filter(PageModel.url == url)

    schema = CollectionSchema()
    return schema.dump(result, many=True), 200
```

Comment: Much much neater. However I get the followingn error: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Don't know how to join to <class '__main__.CollectionModel'>. Please use the .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as providing an explcit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity.
`

Comment: It would be easier if you show here you sqlalchemy models definition

Comment: I've added those.

Comment: I fixed my typo in join definition, please try now @TheMightyLlama

Comment: This works although it doesn't get me where I'm aiming for. It returns `[
    {
        "wikiPageID": 1
    }
]` and what I was looking for was all references which exist within a collection where it containins a page with url x

`[
    {
        "publishDate": "15/09/1980",
        "langCode": "EN",
        "suffix": ".gov.uk",
        "youtubeId": "",
        "type": "article",
        "description": "ssdfsdfsdf",
        "url": "asdfsdfsd.com",
        "langCheck": false,
        "isGov": "1",
        "domain": "government",
        "title": "Article summary"
    }
]`

Comment: Could you provide some example? Some db state, request args and expected output?